# AttributeError: 'Lines_LineSeries_LineIterator_DataAccessor_Strateg' object has no attribute 'analyers'

Tags: python, pycharm, stock, backtrader

I've searched for this question on the internet and I didn't find any suitable answers, so I'm posting this question. My code is in this [link](https://pastebin.com/gDTX1NiP).

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Lines_LineSeries_LineIterator_DataAccessor_Strateg' object has no attribute 'analyzers'
```

The error is actually coming from this line in the file lineseries.py, which comes with pycharm when installed:

```
return getattr(self.lines, name)
```

If you want to see the full code, it is in this [link](https://pastebin.com/19k0ptLp).
I went to every link that showed up in the search, but none of them helped. I tried deleting the 'self' in the line above as someone suggested on Github, but that didn't work.

Thanks for all the help. I know my code is pretty long, so sorry for that.

*Note: I'm using windows 10 with the version python 3.7 installed on my system.*

Comment: Please include full stack trace

Comment: It looks like you misspelled "analyzers" as "analyers"

Comment: @erictruett sorry about that. The variable was originally named that and I forgot to change it.